# How to read spreadsheet which made public using Java with google api?

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-drive-api, spreadsheet

I want to read the data from one of the public [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTe-Cmpii1CsnufmSER7ObEuhBb4TGO29RRwcEAQjW8PYkHKQMfUvriPk2LPXyCm8HMKCIvNFXSqJkU/pubhtml#) which is in pubhtml.

How can I read above spreadsheet using google-api?

I already tried following steps but getting an error:

1. I used [google API doc](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java) with my spreadsheet id.
2. Example:

```
sheet-id- 2PACX-1vTe-
Cmpii1CsnufmSER7ObEuhBb4TGO29RRwcEAQjW8PYkHKQMfUvriPk2LPXyCm8HMKCIvNFXSqJkU
```

3. Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Requested entity was not found.",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Requested entity was not found.",
  "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at Quickstart.main(Quickstart.java:108)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're providing the correct `spreadsheetID`. Error implies there's no spreaddsheet found.

You can use this [spreadsheets.values.get Try-it](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) to validate that. If it gives off the same error, it means you need to recheck your `spreadsheetID`.

This is what a [spreadsheetID](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#spreadsheet_id) looks like:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qpyC0XzvTcKT6EISywvqESX3A0MwQoFDE8p-Bll4hps/edit#gid=0
```

**spreadsheetID**:

> 1qpyC0XzvTcKT6EISywvqESX3A0MwQoFDE8p-Bll4hps

Comment: thanks for the help. check this url,this is spead-sheet ( [link] https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTe-Cmpii1CsnufmSER7ObEuhBb4TGO29RRwcEAQjW8PYkHKQMfUvriPk2LPXyCm8HMKCIvNFXSqJkU/pubhtml ) and hope spead-sheet id will be like - ** 2PACX-1vTe-Cmpii1CsnufmSER7ObEuhBb4TGO29RRwcEAQjW8PYkHKQMfUvriPk2LPXyCm8HMKCIvNFXSqJkU .**


and i tried with your api there also getting same error:
` {
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
} `

Comment: is that spreadsheet yours? I updated my answer for what a spreadsheetID looks like.

Comment: spread -sheet is not mine. that is one of the business center share with public to see daily activity. i want to read that value in my java code.

Comment: can you share the spreadsheet link, just to confirm? If you're using correct spreadsheetID, then the issue might be permissions wherein you're not allowed to access.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTe-Cmpii1CsnufmSER7ObEuhBb4TGO29RRwcEAQjW8PYkHKQMfUvriPk2LPXyCm8HMKCIvNFXSqJkU/pubhtml#

Comment: Thanks. I see the problem is that the owner has "published the spreadsheet to the web". No wonder. If you want to operate on it, you need to ask the owner of the file to  "share the raw file" to you instead (not the 'published to web' version) with 'read' permissions at least (since you only want to read the file).  Hope that helps.